# Fortran: Matrix value changing when using CGESV from LAPACK

Tags: performance, fortran, linear-algebra

I am solving a system of linear equations using the LAPACK method CGESV with very large matrices. So far everything works ok, but there is an issue with computation time. I am copying the matrix to a temporary matrix since I use it repeatedly before passing it into CGESV. That copying of the matrix takes a very long time considering the method is called 1000+ times in a loop. Here is a rough illustration of what I am currently doing:

```
  do 1 i=1,1000
    Atemp = A(:,:,i) !takes about 2.5 sec to compute 
    CGESV(x,x,Atemp,x,x,b,x,x)
1 continue
```

where 'b' is a vector and Atemp is 10,000x10,000. I'd like to do something like this:

```
  do 1 i=1,1000
    CGESV(x,x,A(:,:,i),x,x,b,x,x)
1 continue
```

but the values in 'A' get changed and I can no longer reuse it. I need to increase the efficiency since it is the difference between 1+ hour versus ~4 minute  in computation time.

My question is: is there a way to copy matrices quickly? If not, is there a way I can tell CGESV to return the same matrix? I only need the 'b' vector anyway. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: how large is Atemp (best add some indication of the dimensions of your problem in the question)

Comment: Argument `b` is a NxnbRHS matrix, where nbRHS is the number of right hand side vectors. Many linear systems may be solved at once, if matrix A remains the same. Would it be a problem to provide all right hand side at once if `A(:,:,1)` does not change ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The A matrix changes in every iteration but I use it in other parts of the code that I have not included so I need the original to remain intact.

Comment: if it is really `A(:,:,i)` inside the loop, then your claim that it takes 2.5s to copy 1/1000 of it would mean that A itself is on the order of a TB? If not, then I seriously doubt your claims about the timings.

Comment: "rough illustration" are the words I used. The loop is much more complicated then what I showed. I tried to simplify it to get the general idea across. The A matrix is just a 10,000x10,000 that is updated each loop, but that matrix is used in several locations throughout the loop so I need the value retained. I copy a 10,000x10,000 matrix at two points in my code and I have timed them both to be 2-2.5 second.

Comment: First, from your code, `A` is a 3D matrix, but you say it's 10000x10000? Secondly, now you say copying the whole of A takes 2-2.5 seconds, but in your question it says that `A(:,:,i)` takes 2-2.5 seconds? I understand that the actual code might be much more complicated, but at least these statements are confusing.

Comment: OK, I see you updated the question, but there it now says that Atemp is 10000x10000. That would make A 10000x10000x1000 (since it has an additional dimension running over i from 1 to 1000?

Comment: When I say takes 2-2.5 seconds, I am saying this Atemp = A(:,:,i) takes that amount of time to compile. That is, coping the 10,000x10,000 elements from one matrix to another takes 2-2.5 seconds. 'A' is technically not a three dimensional matrix. I have written it that way because I was not sure how to represent that the matrix is changing every iteration so I added the extra dimension.

Comment: that makes more sense, but your example code is misleading then. 2-2.5 s for a 1.6GB copy is a lot, but possible. Still, cgesv also has to read the entire matrix besides also doing a lot of computation, so I don't see how you would go from 1+ hour to 4min even if you eliminated the entire copy. How did you profile the (complex) loop, and how much time does cgesv take?

Comment: I suppose that was my fault. The times were referring to my code not the sample bit. The entire time to run my code with the copies takes 1+ hour, but without takes around 4 min. That is all relative though since the loop size changes depending on our needs from 500-1000. The code above is a showing a simplified version of a section of my code. That section of the code takes again about 2.5 sec to compute. I use cpu_time at the beginning and end of the loop and subtract the difference.

Comment: If just removing the copy affects the loop size (since A will be totally incorrect I guess) then your measurement is wrong. Please do an actual profiling of a correct, working version of your code. Then you'll know where it really spends the most time. The copy as you're written it should be optimal with any recent compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this

```
  do 1 i=1,1000
    Atemp = A(:,:,i) !takes about 2.5 sec to compute 
    CGESV(x,x,Atemp,x,x,b,x,x)
1 continue
```

to this

```
  atemp = a
  do i=1,1000
    CGESV(x,x,atemp(:,:,i),x,x,b,x,x)
  end do
```

may well show a slight improvement in execution speed.  Not due to the modernisation of the loop statements but due to the single, large, copy rather than the repeated smaller copies.  The modernisation of the loop statements is just for my fun.

Comment: I downvoted because this is not necessarily a good solution. If you use large array copies, then yes, it is possible that the compiler will use e.g. streaming stores. There will be a difference then between the first code and second, only if the separate copies are small enough to not trigger the streaming stores. But then that is also what you want, since it's going to be reused immediately in cgesv.